# Rendering static HTML with hamlet

Tags: haskell, hamlet, static-html

How can I use the [`hamlet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hamlet) framework to generate static HTML pages from inside Haskell?

*Note:* This question intentionally doesn't show research effort. For my research effort, see the Q&A-style answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hamlet` yields QuasiQuoters that are evaluated to [`blaze`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html) expressions. Using [`Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String.renderHtml`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.7.0.0/docs/Text-Blaze-Html-Renderer-String.html) you can render them to a string.

Let's start with a simple non-HTML example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Text.Hamlet

greet name = [shamlet|Hello world #{name}|]
-- This prints "Hello world John Foo"
main = putStrLn $ renderHtml $ greet "John Foo"
```

For increased efficiency, you could also use `Text` instead of `String` [`Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text.renderHtml`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html-0.7.0.0/docs/Text-Blaze-Html-Renderer-Text.html)

Writing this to a file is not different from the standard Haskell approach. You can do this, for example, by using `writeFile` instead of `putStrLn`. You only need to modify the last line

```
main = do writeFile "greet.txt" $ renderHtml $ greet "John Foo"
```

Now we only need to add HTML markup instead of using plain text. See [the Shakespeare documentation](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates) for further reference.

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Text.Hamlet

greet name = [shamlet|
                $doctype 5
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Greeting for #{name}
                    <body>
                        <h2>
                            Hello world #{name}|]

main = writeFile "greet.html" $ renderHtml $ greet "John Foo"
```

`greet.html` now contains a statically rendered greeting HTML.