# Render hamlet template from file

Tags: haskell, hamlet

Assuming I have the following [`shakespeare`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare) template code:

```
$doctype 5
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>This is a test
        <div>Value of test variable: #{testVariable}
```

in the file `mytemplate.hamlet`.

How can I render it using [`shamletFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hamlet-1.1.7.6/docs/Text-Hamlet.html#v%3ashamletFile) without explicitly pasting the template in the source code?

*Note:* This question was answered immediately in a Q&A-Style manner and therefore intentionally does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21313534/2597135) for information on how any why to render `hamlet` templates as static files.

The only major difference is that you need to use Template Haskell's `$(...)` operator to evaluate the `Q Exp` that is yielded by `shamletFile`. Here's a full example that assumes your `mytemplate.hamlet` is located in the same directory as your Haskell file:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml)
import Text.Blaze.Html
import Text.Hamlet

-- | The main template
renderTemplate :: String -> String
renderTemplate testVariable = renderHtml ( $(shamletFile "mypage.hamlet") )

main = do
    putStrLn $ renderTemplate "foobar"
```

When executed, it prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body><h2>This is a test</h2>
<div>Value of test variable: foobar</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that in your application you might need to use either `shamletFile`, `xshamletFile`, `hamletFile` or `ihamletFile`. See [the Hackage documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hamlet-1.1.7.6/docs/Text-Hamlet.html#v:shamletFile) and [the Yesod book on Shakespearean templates](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates) for information on when to use any of those.